# How to set a size for JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, preferredsize

[image]

As you can see, it's ugly to have these kind of `JMenuItem`s. The width of the menu items is quite small.

Here is the code:

```
JMenu menuOne=new JMenu("MenuOne");
    JMenu menuTwo=new JMenu("MenuTwo");
    JMenu menuThree=new JMenu("MenuThree");
    JMenu menuFour=new JMenu("MenuFour");
    JMenuBar mbar=new JMenuBar();
    //add the menu to menubar
    mbar.add(menuOne);
    JMenuItem OneItOne=new JMenuItem("1");

    JMenuItem OneItTwo=new JMenuItem("2");
    menuOne.add(OneItOne);
    menuOne.addSeparator();
    menuOne.add(OneItTwo);
    mbar.add(menuTwo);
    mbar.add(menuThree);
    mbar.add(menuFour);
    setJMenuBar(mbar);
```

Simply adding some blanks in the String is okay (e.g. `"1     "`), but is there any better way to set a preferred length of `JMenuItem`? I've tried `OneItTwo.setSize()`, but failed.

Comment: The size of the menu is defined by the preferred size of it's content.  I'm not sure what it is you want to achieve...

Comment: @Extreme Coders Not enough reputations.

Comment: @MadProgrammer OneItOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30)); worked.

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setPreferredSize(new Dimension(...));` works on menu items. `setMinimumSize` does not work though; it does not seem to be honored by the menu layout manager, so if you want to set a minimum that may be overridden by having larger content, or you want to set a minimum or preferred width without changing the height, you must override `getPreferredSize()` in a subclass. E.g.,

```
menuOne.add(new JMenuItem("1") {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
        d.width = Math.max(d.width, 400); // set minimums
        d.height = Math.max(d.height, 300);
        return d;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can use `setPreferredSize` to specify the dimensions you need. You can specify the width to whatever you want (200 looks good to me). You can allow the height to remain autosized based on the amount of menu items by getting the default preferred size:

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem();
item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, item.getPreferredSize().height));
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with comments explaining how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the size of your JMenuItem (width in my case). You can change the width with this solution :

```
 JMenuItem returnMenu = new JMenuItem(action) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension preferred = super.getPreferredSize();
                Dimension minimum = getMinimumSize();
                Dimension maximum = getMaximumSize();
                preferred.width = Math.min(Math.max(preferred.width, 200),
                        maximum.width);
                preferred.height = Math.min(Math.max(preferred.height, minimum.height),
                        maximum.height);
                return preferred;
            }
        };
```

I just reused this solution : [JMenuItem setMinimumSize doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345902/jmenuitem-setminimumsize-doesnt-work)

It works better as you an see.
Selected solution
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGoWI.png)
This solution
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M4Vz.png)
I grant you, this is similar to the selected answer.